# why when use hostname -I command to show 2 ip address?

Tags: pi-3, networking

I will use `hostname -I` command display 2 IP address how there is 2 IP address in and what it the difference between them?

Comment: Note: you're getting a lot of answers because you haven't actually showed us what you are seeing...

Answer (score 1):

From what I can read around, hostname -I will show up addresses and a single host can have multiple IP addresses set up (normally it's one IP address per interface but it's very flexible so you can have multiple IP addresses in a single interface, for example). And what do they mean? Not much, only that a single host con be connected to more than one network at a given moment in time. Think of a router, they could have a plethora of addresses set up.

Answer (score 1):

Because the Pi3 has 2 interfaces!

Read `man hostname`

Answer (score 1):

On a single line, you will see two IP adresses. The first IP address is the IPv4 address. The second one on the right is the IPv6 address. IPv6 is longer and was introduced so that we could internet the galaxy. IPv4 is shorter and still in use. IPv4 remains more practical for humans because of its brevity.

Comment: You will only see IPv6 if you have a router which allocates one